# how to upgrade jQuery 1.5.1 to 3.0 without using plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to upgrade jQuery 1.5.1 to 3.0
but due to organization restriction not able to use any plugin.
So tried to update jar manually as
jquery-1.5.1.min.js  to jquery-2.2.4.min.js
and using jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js

facing below errors:
SCRIPT5009: "jQuery" is undefined

SCRIPT5007:  the value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a function object

SCRIPT5007:  the value of the property 'jQuery' is null or undefined, not a function object

I have added below

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge"/

but didn't work.

let me know if there is any other way to do it.
or am I using the correct UI version jar? which UI version jar would be compatible with 2.2.4.js?
any URLs to download jar of v3.0? and where to check the syntax updated according to versions.

please consider this is the first time I am working on jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upgrade without jQuery migrate, you will need to take each version and check/ fix the breaking changes.

From 1.5.1 to 2.2.4 there are so many changes and methods that are removed or they changed.
Depending, on how much jQuery is used, you may need to re-write most of the code.
There is no plug and play alternative.

I suggest jQuery migrate, but if you don't want to use that, then good luck